# Daemon to restart a process if it gets killed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am looking for a daemon which can restart a process if it gets killed. I do not want to use script which keeps on monitoring using ps command. Is there any way by which I can get signals from kernel if a process get killed with which I can restart the process. Is there any open source daemon available for that?

Comment: you can create your daemon that can monitor your process.

Comment: refer https://superuser.com/questions/507576/how-to-automatically-restart-a-linux-background-process-if-it-fails

Comment: Take a look at this, http://godrb.com/

Comment: Most linux distros nowadays use systemd, which can do that . Otherwise, use supervisord

Comment: give a try to a supervisor, probably https://immortal.run/ could help

Comment: If you linux distro based on `systemd`, then it could be done out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) should do the work.

Comment: I do not have python support on the device. Is there any other daemon that will not
replace the init process?